# Button once clicked keeps turning blue

Tags: xcode, ios5, button, uibutton, settings

in my app I have a textfield and then a button behind that(which occupies the whole screen) so that once the button is tapped, the keyboard for the textfield will disappear. My question was, how do I configure the button attributes so that the button does not flash blue when it is tapped?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using hyperlink as button, and hyperlink's color changes once it is visited, so you can change this using css

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```